# how to resize images during upload with Cloudinary

Tags: php, cloudinary

I'm using `Cloudinary` in a `PHP 8.1.2` site.

I'm new to using `Cloudinary`. For me, getting complete info on how to do things with `Cloudinary` is very difficult to do. I have an upload script but I would like to resize images uploaded in a specific form to about 150w x 200h.  How do I do this using the `Cloudinary` code I'm currently using?

I could do this in `PHP`, I'd like to figure out how `Cloudinary` does it - for future reference.

```
#image-upload.html

<?php
// my cloudinary creds
require_once('../includes/cloudinary_creds.php');

// load cloudinary classes/files
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

// instance var
$cc = new CloudinaryCreds();

// needed cloudinary files
use Cloudinary\Cloudinary;
use Cloudinary\Configuration\Configuration;

// Use the UploadApi class for uploading assets
use Cloudinary\Api\Upload\UploadApi;

Configuration::instance( $cc->get_cloudinary_url() );

$upload = new UploadApi();

$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';

if( isset($action) && $action=="Submit" ){
  if ( is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']) ) {

    $tmp_name = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];

    // lose extension on image
    $parts = explode('.', $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
    $image_name = $parts[0];

    $image_array = (new UploadApi())->upload($tmp_name, [
                                                         'public_id' => $image_name,
                                                         'folder' => 'student_images',
                                                         'overwrite' => TRUE ]);

 } // end is_uploaded_file
} // end isset()
?>
```

This code works to upload an image to my `Cloudinary` account, but the image can be very large. What do I need to do to resize an image before the actual upload?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: The images uploaded to your Cloudinary account can be [delivered using on-the-fly transformations](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/transformation_basics_tutorial#transform_assets_on_the_fly). For the case that you will need to resize the image before uploading, you may checkout the approach as [described in this document](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php_imagemagick/php_imagemagick_image_resizing.htm)

Comment: @epasos_573 thanks, but one of my problems with `cloudinary` docs is they give you some snippet of code to resize an image, but they don't tell you what include files you need to make it work.  You need to add some `Cloudinary` classes, but which ones?  I would love `ImageMagick`, but I'm on a shared hosting plan and I don't believe they have `ImageMagick` installed.